# Connect this to a form to have an incrementing label when the radio button is clicked

Tags: vb.net

This is a program in VB.Net 2012 that I have made for my project. I hope that you can help me.

I have tried this code in the inventory button code, but it does not work.

```
Dim rad1 As String = 0
Dim rad2 As String = 0
Dim rad3 As String = 0
Dim rad4 As String = 0
Dim rad5 As String = 0
Dim rad6 As String = 0
Dim rad7 As String = 0
Dim rad8 As String = 0

Dim siomairice As String
Dim friedsiomai As String
Dim siomai As String
Dim threesiomai As String
Dim coke As String
Dim sprite As String
Dim rc As String
Dim sevenup As String

If rad1 = radS2.Checked Then
    siomairice = rad1
    siomairice = siomairice + 1
    siomairice = Form5.Label1.Text
End If
If rad2 = radS2.Checked Then
    friedsiomai = rad2
    friedsiomai = friedsiomai + 1
    friedsiomai = Form5.Label2.Text
End If
If rad3 = radS3.Checked Then
    siomai = rad3
    siomai = siomai + 1
    siomai = Form5.Label3.Text
End If
If rad4 = radS4.Checked Then
    threesiomai = rad3
    threesiomai = threesiomai + 1
    threesiomai = Form5.Label4.Text
End If
If rad5 = radD1.Checked Then
    coke = rad5
    coke = coke + 1
    coke = Form5.Label5.Text
End If
If rad6 = radD2.Checked Then
    sprite = rad6
    sprite = sprite + 1
    sprite = Form5.Label6.Text
End If
If rad7 = radD3.Checked Then
    rc = rad7
    rc = rc + 1
    rc = Form5.Label7.Text
End If
If rad8 = radD4.Checked Then
    sevenup = rad8
    sevenup = sevenup + 1
    sevenup = Form5.Label8.Text
End If
```

It does not have any error or warning in the program itself but it does not have any response when I click it.

Comment: Why should it have any response? You don't change any UI properties. You just assign some values to some variables. Furthermore, check the declaration of `rad1` to `rad8`. You declare it as `String`, but `0` is definitely not a `String` (this is the first place where implicit conversion happens). The second place is the comparison `rad1 = radS2.Checked`. `radS2.Checked` is of type `Boolean` and it makes no sense to compare it to a `String`. So declare your `rad1 ... As Boolean = False`.

Answer (score 0):

This code will never work. For example `If rad1 = radS2.Checked Then`-- `rad1` is a string with value of "0". I assume `radS2.Checked` is radio button property, which is `boolean`. You comparing string value "0" and boolean, which is `True` or `False` in its string equivalent.
So, the code inside `If` will never execute

Second issue, for example

```
siomai = Form5.Label3.Text
```

If you want to display text on the label, it needs to be

```
Form5.Label3.Text = siomai
```

Third issue - the whole logic is crazy. Should be something like this:

```
private _rad1Clicks as Integer

private sub rad1_Click (sender as object, e as eventArgs) Handles rad1.Click
    _rad1Clicks += 1
    myForm.myLabel.Text = _rad1Clicks.ToString()
End sub
```